# How can I see the 'Custom Options' metadata following Save As in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, metadata, qgis-2.10

In QGIS 2.10 Pisa, I've right-clicked a layer in the TOC and used Saved As ... to save a shapefile with a new name. During this process, I used the Custom Options (Data Source and Layer) to include some metadata. The new shapefile was created just fine as always. However, it seems this metadata can't be found with the new shapefile. How can I see this metadata?